# How would velocity of sound, the fundamental frequency and wavelength of sound vary when the temperature of an organ pipe is increased?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, wavelength

*Here is my approach to this:*

---

**neglecting any thermal expansion of the pipe:**

By the Laplace formula for the speed of sound,

> $V=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma P}{\rho}}$  where P is the pressure, $\gamma$ is the adiabatic constant and $\rho$ is the density of the medium.

Assuming the gas to be an ideal gas, we can use the ideal gas equation.
Hence we have:

> $V=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma RT}{M}}$  where R is the gas constant, T is the absolute temperature, and M is the molar mass of air

---

So, when we **increase the temperature**, clearly, the **velocity would increase as well**. Coming to the fundamental frequency, we know

> $f_0$ (fundamental frequency) $\alpha$ V (velocity of sound)

Hence, the fundamental frequency would also increase.

---

But how would we get the variance of the wavelength with temperature?  I thought of using the relation

> $V=f\lambda$ where V is the velocity of sound, f is the frequency and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

According to which, the wavelength should also increase but according to my book, that's not right. Why does this happen?

Comment: so thermal expansion of the organ pipe itself is neglected?

Comment: @sleepy yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:  Sound waves in an organ pipe are examples of standing waves.  The allowed wavelengths of a standing wave on (for example) a string are not arbitrary, but are instead determined by the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The wavelength is independent of temperature.

[image]

You can see here that the wavelength depends only on the length of the organ pipe and the *harmonic* of the resonance, rather than the temperature of the gas itself.

The only way of changing the wavelength is by increasing the *harmonic* or the length of the pipe itself.

Hope this helps answer your question.